# Dynamic Menu in Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, menu, menubar

I have a bunch of Dock Widgets that the User is free to close and want to provide a menu in my `QMenuBar` that reopens each of them individually. So possibly every time the menu is opened, the list of options will be different.

Is there any event or hook that I can use to recreate the menu whenever it is opened? The only thing I could find was the `triggered` event, but that is only generated after I already selected something.

Otherwise I would have to monitor all dock widget actions or I could use a timer that periodically recreates the menu - both solutions don't sound very appealing.

Comment: Could you add an event handler for when the dock widget closes and then just update the menu when it closes?

Comment: It looks like the `QDockWidget` has an event handler `void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)`.  Is that suitable?

Comment: You can connect to `QMenu::aboutToShow` signal and re-fill the menu when it's triggered.

Comment: I think you're trying to bypass the logic -- you should keep your dock widgets visibility status in sync with the corresponding `QAction`s in the menu, not trying to repopulate the menu itself. What if then you want to add a toolbar with the same actions?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#toggleViewAction is the typical flow most program use.  Add that to your View or Toolbars menu for each dockwidget and you are done.

Comment: I went with the `QMenu::aboutToShow` option for now. Don't know, why I did not see it, but it works very nice now.
`toggleViewAction` sounds good too, but I wanted to show only the menus that are currently hidden.
Using `closeEvent` would probably be the somewhat cleaner solution, however I add DockWidgets at different parts of my program, and this way I only have to change my program at one place.